# Redraw canvas on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I already opened a question about this canvas I'm creating here but with a different issue at: [Make rectangle overlay image with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612333/make-rectangle-overlay-image-with-canvas)

I'd like to know if it's possible to animate the radius of an arch on mouseover?
Here's what I've: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJjt7/3/)

```
// Options
var maxImageWidth = 250,
    maxImageHeight = 196,
    radius = 50;

var canvas = $('#ddayCanvas'),
    canvasWidth = canvas.width(),
    canvasHeight = canvas.height(),
    sectorColor = $('.product-box').css('background-color'),
    context = canvas[0].getContext('2d'),
    imageSrc = canvas.data('image');  


function drawDday (option) {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);         

    if (typeof option != 'undefined'){
        radius = option;
    }    

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {

        var imageWidth = imageObj.width,
            imageHeight = imageObj.height;

        if (imageWidth > maxImageWidth){
            imageHeight = imageHeight - (imageWidth - maxImageWidth);
            imageWidth = maxImageWidth;
        }

        if (imageHeight > maxImageHeight) {
            imageWidth = imageWidth - (imageHeight - maxImageHeight);
            imageHeight = maxImageHeight;
        }

        context.drawImage(imageObj, Math.ceil((canvasWidth - imageWidth) / 2), Math.ceil((canvasHeight - imageHeight) / 2), imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // Why does this rectangle not overlay the previous image?
        context.fillStyle = sectorColor;
        context.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        context.arc(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.fill();
    };


    imageObj.src = imageSrc;  

}

drawDday(); 

canvas.hover(function(){
    drawDday(90);
}, function(){
    drawDday(20);
});
```

I've tried to call the function with a parameter for the radius on hover, and "overwrite" the canvas with clearRect. But unfortunately it only gives me a flickr effect...

EDIT

I just realized that the mouseover/out works when the initial radius is bigger then the hover radius. Very strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reloading the image with each drawDday call.  This will cause the flicker effect.  Try loading the image once and reusing the imageObj reference to draw to the canvas.

imageObj is loaded once and reused for each drawDday call. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr5k9/4/

```
function drawDday (radius) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    context.drawImage(imageObj, Math.ceil((canvasWidth - imageWidth) / 2), Math.ceil((canvasHeight - imageHeight) / 2), imageWidth, imageHeight);
    context.fillStyle = sectorColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    context.arc(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}
```

Edit: Please note the context.beginPath() and context.closePath().  This lets the canvas sub-system know that each time the function is called it's a new path.  Otherwise the new path will combine with the old one.

Edit: With simple animation effect on mouse move: http://jsfiddle.net/CvuyN/2/

Comment: That's great thanks, but is there also a way to make this hover effect animated (maybe with jQuery's `animate()`)?

Comment: That's cool but I need this effect on mouseover without a permanent user interaction..

Comment: Do you mean this animation should only happen on initial mouseover event and then not happen again?

Comment: No, on each mouseover event it should increase the radius with an animation and on mouseout it should animate back to the initial radius. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/vzn7u/

Comment: Caution now entering the murky world of canvas animation :)  enjoy!  http://jsfiddle.net/PLDUq/2/

Comment: awesome! I'll accept your answer, thanks a lot! But one last question, is there a possibility to make this more look like an ease effect of jQuery's animate?

Comment: With a little more maths: http://jsfiddle.net/PLDUq/3/ Adjust ease and speed variables to your liking.

Comment: Could you have a look at the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655354/prevent-requestanimationframe-from-running-all-the-time