# Prevent requestAnimationFrame from running all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'd like to know how to call the `animate` function through `requestAnimationFrame` only when it's realy needed. Currently the `animate` is called all the time what generates an overhead I guess.

I already tried inside my `animate` function to compare `targetRadius` and the inital `radius` and return false once they are the same. Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.

Can someone explain me how to solve that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLDUq/5/)

HTML:

```
  <canvas id="ddayCanvas" width="288" height="288" data-image="http://www.topdesignmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/64.png">
    <div>
        <div class="product-image"></div>
        <div class="product-box">...</div>
        <a href="#" class="overlay">...</a>
    </div>    
  </canvas>
```

JS:

```
// Options
var maxImageWidth = 250,
    maxImageHeight = 196;

var canvas = $('#ddayCanvas'),
    canvasWidth = canvas.width(),
    canvasHeight = canvas.height(),
    sectorColor = $('.product-box').css('background-color'),
    context = canvas[0].getContext('2d'),
    imageSrc = canvas.data('image'),
    imageObj = new Image(),
    imageWidth, imageHeight,
    mouseover = false;

    imageObj.onload = function() {
        imageWidth = this.width;
        imageHeight = this.height;

        if (imageWidth > maxImageWidth){
            imageHeight = imageHeight - (imageWidth - maxImageWidth);
            imageWidth = maxImageWidth;
        }

        if (imageHeight > maxImageHeight) {
            imageWidth = imageWidth - (imageHeight - maxImageHeight);
            imageHeight = maxImageHeight;
        }

        drawDday(90); 
    };

    imageObj.src = imageSrc;  

function drawDday (radius) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    context.drawImage(imageObj, Math.ceil((canvasWidth - imageWidth) / 2), Math.ceil((canvasHeight - imageHeight) / 2), imageWidth, imageHeight);
    context.fillStyle = sectorColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    context.arc(canvasWidth/2, canvasHeight/2, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    // Check out the console
    console.log('test');
}


var radius = baseRadius = 90,
    targetRadius = 110,
    ease = 50,
    speed = 2;

function animate(){
    if(mouseover){
        radius += ((targetRadius-radius)/ease)*speed;
    } else {
        radius -= ((radius-baseRadius)/ease)*speed;
    }
    if(radius > targetRadius) radius = targetRadius;
    if(radius < baseRadius) radius = baseRadius;

    drawDday(radius);   
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

canvas.on('mouseover', function(e){
    mouseover = true;
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    mouseover = false;
});
```

Comment: The easing function is asymptotic.  It may not reach the target value for some time.  You might want to try Math.floor(), Math.ceil() or Math.round() to make sure it reaches the target value.

Comment: The radius is a decimal number and I've used as you suggested Math.ceil() but this has no affect at all. Why should it?

Comment: This demonstrates the asymptotic nature of the ease function and why your comparison test is probably not working: http://jsfiddle.net/EHEuZ/1/

Comment: I'm aware of that but it doesn't solve the problem at all, or did I misunderstand anything? I think the problem is that the function animate is an endless loop as `drawDday(radius);` and `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` are always invoked. But I'm not sure how to "break" the function when it's not necessary to recall it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement a *condition* so you can break the loop, for example (adopt as needed):

```
var isRunning = true;

function loop() {

    ... funky stuff here ...

    /// test condition before looping
    if (isRunning) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Now when you set `isRunning` to `false` the loop will break. For convenience it's recommended that you have a method to start and stop the loop:

```
function startLoop(state) {

    if (state && !isRunning) {
        isRunning = true;
        loop();             /// starts loop

    } else if (!state && isRunning) {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The condition can be set by anything you need it to be set by, for example on a callback after an animation has finished etc. The important part is that the condition flag is available to both scopes using it (ie. most commonly in the global scope).

**UPDATE**:

More specific in this case is that your condition (radius) will never reach the condition required to eventually stop the loop.

Here is what you can do to fix this:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PLDUq/6/)

```
var isPlaying = false;

function animate(){
    /**
     * To make sure you will reach the condition required you need
     * to either make sure you have a fall-out for the steps or the
     * step will become 0 not adding/subtracting anything so your
     * checks below won't trigger. Here we can use a simple max of
     * the step and a static value to make sure the value is always > 0
    */
    if(mouseover){
        radius += Math.max( ((targetRadius-radius)/ease)*speed, 0.5);
    } else {
        radius -= Math.max( ((radius-baseRadius)/ease)*speed,   0.5);
    }

    /**
     * Now the checks will trigger properly and we can use the
     * isPlaying flag to stop the loop when targets are reached.
    */
    if(radius >= targetRadius) {
        radius = targetRadius;
        isPlaying = false;              /// stop loop after this
    } else if (radius <= baseRadius) {
        radius = baseRadius;
        isPlaying = false;              /// stop loop after this
    }
    
    drawDday(radius);

    /// loop?
    if (isPlaying === true) requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

In order to trigger the loop we use a method that will check if the loop is running, if not it will reset the `isPlaying` flag and start the loop. We do this inside both `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
canvas.on('mouseover', function(e){
    mouseover = true;
    startAnim();

}).on('mouseout', function(){
    mouseover = false;
    startAnim();
});
```

The method is simply checking `isPlaying` and if not set it set it to true and starts the loop - this so that the loop is only started once:

```
function startAnim() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
        isPlaying = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}
```

In the demo I added console logging to show when the loop is running and when targets are hit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm aware of using conditions but in this case it doesn't work for some reason. E.g. there's currently a `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` in the global scope but if I put this in the `mouseover` event it doesn't do anything. Could you give me an example in this special case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the more detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

The reason your `animate` function is being called continuously is because you start off by calling `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` and then each call to `animate` unconditionally calls `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` again. The cycle is never going to be broken unless you use `cancelAnimationFrame` at some point (which you don't), or make sure that `animate` only requests another frame if it's needed.

Another issue is the fact that `radius` will currently never reach either `targetRadius` nor `baseRadius`, and therefore neither of the following will ever be true:

```
if(radius > targetRadius) radius = targetRadius;
if(radius < baseRadius) radius = baseRadius;
```

This isn't directly responsible for the continual calls to `animate`, but since `targetRadius` and `baseRadius` are being used to indicate the end-points of your animation then we need to form some sort of sensible conditional with them.

So, you could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/PLDUq/9/

```
var radius = baseRadius = 50,
    targetRadius = 110,
    ease = 50,
    speed = 12,
    currentAnim;

function animate(){
    if(mouseover){
        radius += ((targetRadius-radius)/ease)*speed;
    } else {
        radius -= ((radius-baseRadius)/ease)*speed;
    }

    drawDday(radius);

    if(Math.round(radius) >= targetRadius) {
        // uses Math.round() to ensure condition can be fulfilled

        radius = targetRadius;
        return; // doesn't call next frame
    }
    if(Math.round(radius) <= baseRadius) {
        radius = baseRadius;
        return; // doesn't call next frame
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

canvas.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (currentAnim) {requestAnimationFrame(currentAnim);}
    // cancels current animation if one is playing to
    // prevent several concurrent loops calling animate()

    mouseover = (e.type === 'mouseenter');

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
});
```